# How to convert and parse text to JSON

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I have a string which is badly formated for `JSON.parse`.
It looks like this:
`user_data = "{'key1':'val','key2':"bad_val with 'quoted' text"}"`

I want to convert this somehow and parse with `JSON.parse()`. If it weren't for this `bad_val` simple `replace(/'/g, '"')` would help, but with this I'm stuck. What is the correct way of converting this?

Comment: That's not a valid string declaration. Do you mean it's represented like `user_data = \`"{'key1':'val','key2':"bad_val with 'quoted' text"}"\``?

Comment: @CertainPerformance: How is your example different? I just character compared the two and can't find a difference.

Comment: Perhaps you want `user_data.key2.replace(/'/g, '\"')`.

Comment: How is this JSON-like string generated/retreived? The best solution would be to correct the source of this string.. it shouldn't produce this format

Comment: @Flater His code cannot be declared as a Javascript string; mine can. Need to know what your actual string is

Comment: @Flater the difference is the `\`` characters, which allow to declare a string too in JS, so that there is no escaping problem with using `"` or `'` inside the string

Comment: You should not "fix" the string, but fix the source of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON.stringify() for converting it into JSON.
For example:

```
var user_data = "{'key1':'val','key2':"bad_val with 'quoted' text"}";
var jsonObj = JSON.stringify(user_data);
```

It will return valid JSON format.

Comment: `JSON.stringify`   an object to json string, if you pass `jsonObj` in `JSON.parse` you will only get a string and not an object

Answer (score 0):

I assume the `user_data` is a bad formatted JSON which cannot be parsed with `JSON.parse`. If it's not possible to correct that string, then as a simple work around, you may try `eval`

```
let convertedUserData;
eval('convertedUserData = ' + user_data);
```

Though, this means executing script within that `user_data` string, therefore be aware of security issue. Again, not recommended at all

Comment: You should also mention the implications of using `eval`; it adds serious security issues.

Comment: Good point, thanks str, added